# Creating objects suddenly begins failing after they have been loaded in memory successfully

Tags: iis, memory, vb6, activex, corruption

**Behavior:**
Application is loaded and being used as expected.
Suddenly, a particular DLL can no longer be loaded. The error message is:

*ActiveX component cannot create object.*
In each case, the object had been created successfully many times before failure. All objects are marked for "retain in memory".

This error is cleared when the application pool is recycled. It may be hours or months before it is seen again.

Issue has happened within two hours of a refresh, as well as never happened in months of uptime.
Issue has happened with hundreds of simultaneous users (heavy usage) and also with 1-3 users.

While the issue is occurring, the process running that application pool cannot create the object that is failing. However it can create any other objects. Memory, CPU, and other resources all remain at normal usage. In addition, other processes (such as a stand-alone exe) can successfully create the object.

The first instance of the issue appeared in mid 2008. There have been less than fifty instances since then, despite a pool of hundreds of servers for it to occur on. All instances except one have failed on the same DLL.

**DLL Failure Info:**
most common - generic data structure implementing a b-tree, has no references other than to its interface. Code consists of arrays and one use of the vb6 Event functionality. The object has not been changed in any way since 2005.
one-time - interop to a .NET module. the failure is occurring when trying to create the interop object, not the .NET object. This object is updated a few times each year.

**Application Environment:**
IIS hosted application
VB6, classic ASP, some interop to minor .NET components
Windows Server 2003 / Windows Server 2008 (both have independently had the problem)

**Attempts to Reproduce:**
Using scripts (and real-life humans) to run the same end-user workflows that our logs reported the days before the issue occurred.
Using scripts to create/destroy suspected objects as fast as possible from multiple simultaneous sessions.
Wild speculation.
No intentional success, but it does manifest randomly on the servers on its own.

**Troubleshooting:**
Code reviews
Test harnesses to investigate upper limits of object creation / destruction
Verification of ability to create object outside of the process experiencing the issue
Monitoring of resources over time on servers under load
Review of IIS, error, and event logs to determine events leading up to issue

**Questions:**
Any ideas on how to reproduce the issue?
What could cause this behavior?
Ideas for bypassing the first two questions in favor of a fast solution?

Comment: I can't help - you've already done everything I would have suggested - but you get an upvote for a really interesting question coupled with a good statement of the problem. Hopefully someone here will shed light on your issue.

Comment: You haven't actually said if the error occurs internal to the VB6 code or in ASP code.

Comment: The CreateObject call that fails is inside VB6 code.

Comment: I changed the DLL base address and it seems to have resolved the problem, but it is too early to tell. The concept is that this would simply avoid whatever was corrupting memory at that location. This would fail if the object itself was corrupting the memory, but I have no reason to think it could.

Answer (score 1):

The DLL isn't on a network drive is it? You can get "glitches" where the drive is not available momentarily that then means COM can't do what it needs and could then fail to notice the drive is available again.

Comment: No, all files are installed locally.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to debug similar problem when accessing ADO/OLEDB stack. Turned out environment got corrupted at some point and ADO classes are registered with InprocServer32 being REG_EXPAND_SZ pointing to %CommonProgramFiles%\System\ado\msado15.dll or similar ot x64 OSes.

Also when you register an application with Restart Manager, on failure the process gets restarted by winlogon process whose environment is different than explorer's one and unfortunately is missing %CommonProgramFiles% -- ouch!

Comment: Procmon shows no unexpected entries in the actions leading up to the failure. Unfortunately, it is not feasible to capture all events until the first instance of the failure due to the unpredictability. Using procmon with an already failed server shows no interesting entries on subsequent failures. The process doesn't register any requests for the object or related registry keys, it appears to fail while trying to instanciate from the object loaded in memory. In your case you were able to see what corruption happened, but did that tell you anything about how it happened or what to do about it?

Comment: (char limit) It would seem that a failure of that type would cause everything (or at least that entire class of objects) to stop working, not just a single object.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a random failure; some race condition.
Try [VMWARE](http://www.vmwarewolf.com/vmware-record-and-play/) to record the state of the machine you run this dll on. When the error happens you can then replay the record and inspect the memory contents. That why you won't have to play `try and catch` the error. At least you will have a solid record of it.

While I can't provide a solution, try `catching` the error and retry loading the dll when this happens after a refresh to the environment.